# How to deploy ASP.NET project with Angular 13 frontend to IIS?

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, asp.net-web-api, angular13

I am trying to setup the solution for a web application which uses ASP.NET with .NET Framework 4.8 for the backend and Angular 13 for the frontend (we cannot use .NET Core or any newer version because some of the libraries we need to use are only available for .NET Framework).

In the solution, the angular project is in the same folder as the backend project (where the sln file is also located). Now, I created a publish profile for the backend project but it is not yet linked to the angular project in any way, so the output folder only contains the files for the backend. In addition to that, I built the angular frontend via `ng build` which generated all of the files I need for the frontend in the `dist` folder.

How can I deploy this to an IIS webserver so users can see and work with the angular frontend and all http requests to the backend are routed to the appropriate controller and action in my ASP.NET application? Are there any tutorials or instructions for this? So far, I was not able to find what I am looking for and I am very confused how I am supposed to make this work in IIS.

Comment: Actually, angular and asp.net application should be deployed into two sites on IIS. The communication between them is realized through the connection to interface of asp.net. So you only need to configure the url that angular can connect to each interface in the asp.net application. Deploy asp.net web api on IIS: https://geeksarray.com/blog/host-asp-net-web-api-in-iis-using-visual-studio-publish Deploy angular on IIS: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-deploy-angular-app-to-an-iis-web-server-complete-setup-337997486423

Comment: @BruceZhang Thanks! Do you have any information on why I need two sites in this scenario? I worked on quite a few ASP.NET Core projects with Angular frontends before and I never needed two sites to host them on IIS, so why do I need two sites here?

Comment: In my opinion, the benefit of this is the separation of front and back ends. If there is a problem after deployment, you can know whether it is angular or asp.net faster. Different sites in IIS use separate application pools, which can reduce the load of a single application pool.

Comment: @BruceZhang Thanks! I have one more question: I need to use Windows Authentication in this project. Do you know how to make this work when running the project via two sites in IIS?

Comment: Two things should be configured. First is enabling CORS on web api application. Because two different sites use two different host name. Enable CORS can allows data to be transferred between two websites without being blocked by domain protection. Second is attaching the windows credential in angular request. When client sends request to angular, it uses the identity of angular site app pool. Angular sends request to web api, it is send by angular app pool. So attach the windows account in this requests can pass windows authentication.

Comment: I'm not an expert on Angular. What I know is `private options = new RequestOptions({ withCredentials: true });   this.http.get(this.baseUrl, this.options)`. Maybe other angular experts know how to attach custom windows account in the request.